# i want to control the error message when calling function return an error

Tags: vb.net, error-handling

i want to customize my own error box and message when an error occur in calling a function .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yToJC.jpg)

i try to use try catch an exception but not doing anything

```
    Try
            L = objGeoFlowDLL.GFCalc_Main(nInputs, nOutputs, sngInputs, sngOutputs)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            '  Me.Close()
        Finally

        End Try
```

Comment: There are many types of exceptions. You are catching the general one. If you want to customize the messages for all possible exceptions then you have to catch each one separately

Comment: its possible to catch all exceptions and give a msgbox and exit the program

Comment: It's possible (maybe even likely given the error message) that the dll you are using is catching the exception and producing the error message.  If you have control of the dll, you need to look at the contents of `GFCalc_Main` (and the things it calls).  If not, your only recourse would be to talk to whoever supplies the dll to you.

Comment: You really need to check those values ranges before passing them to an external dll and inform the user that the input values are not correct. A *Division by Zero* should never happen. Trying to use a try/catch block to avoid testing the values is...

Answer (score 0):

```
Try
  L = objGeoFlowDLL.GFCalc_Main(nInputs, nOutputs, sngInputs, sngOutputs)
Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
  MessageBox.Show("Custom message to be shown when something is divided by zero.")
Catch ex2 As Exception
  MessageBox.Show("Custom message to be shown when any other error occurs.")
End Try
```

Comment: hi ondrej,    still the same the try catch ex doesn't works still give the same pop up error message

Comment: oh ya i forgot to mention the function located inside the dll file . if that make any different on error handling ?

Comment: Then exception handling (and dialog showing) is probably inside that DLL and unless you have source code of it, you wont be able to do anything.